# How do I change what a registry does in Windows (10)?

Tags: windows, registry, microsoft-edge, regedit

I have been trying to take a new tab in edge open right to google. I have tried adding a string value called NewTabPageURL and setting the value to www.google.com in numerous locations, but this hasn't worked. In MicrosoftEdge\ServiceUI, I can see the registry that controls what a new tab will be (their 3 options, blank page, feed, feed and your top websites it is called NewTabPageDisplayOption). I have the value set to 1 which will open a new page with top websites. Can I change what the value 1 does to open to google, or add a new value after 2 that can do this?

Comment: I found another registry string called NewTabPageFlightUrlKind, which I think sets the new tab url because the value is set to about:tabs, and typing this in my home page (google) brings me to what a new tab is. The problem is, I tried to set this value to google, but when I look back it changed itself back to about:tabs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest you to do not modify the registry settings. If you modify the registry settings incorrectly than it can lead MS Edge to get crashed or not work properly.

It is best practice to apply the settings via group policy. group policy will create/ modify registry keys properly.

If we talk about your requirement than it looks like you want to open Google.com in new tab.

You can refer steps below to achieve your requirement via group policy.

(1) Open **Run** Window in your Win 10 OS.

(2) Type **GPEDIT.MSE** in it and press Enter key.

(3) Navigate to location below.

> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Microsoft Edge

(4) Find a policy setting called **Set New Tab Page URL** and double click on it.

(5) Click on **Enabled** radio button.

(6) Set a new URL for New Tab page like below.

[image]

(7) Click on **Apply** button and close the Window.

> Note that this policy is depended upon other policy called **Allow Web Content on New Page**.

So you also need to find this policy from the similar location and **Enabled** it. Otherwise your above policy setting will get ignored.

[image]

For more information, You can refer the link below.

[New Tab page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/deploy/group-policies/new-tab-page-settings-gp)

You also need to check that above settings are not controlled by your administrator/ organization. Due to that reason, This policy settings also get ignored.

Comment: I am running windows 10 home edition, I am the owner. You are right about edge not working properly, I tried to change permissions for the ServiceUI key and I had to restore the registry. I don't have gpedit.mse, is there an equivalent for home edition?

Comment: I enabled group policy editor. Set new tab page url does not seem to be an entry in Microsoft Edge.

Comment: I checked it and find that this policy available in a Win 10 Professional but it is not available in Win 10 Home or Win 10 Enterprise. So as an alternative way you can create registry key or MDM setting. For that you can refer the same link from my previous answer.